# Raphael and IE. Mouseout workaround

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, raphael, mouseover, mouseout

I've run into an issue using Raphael for SVG effects on an IE browser. When I mouseover an object, the animation occurs as expected. On mouseout, however, the mouseout action is never called, so the object(s) are stuck in their mouseover state.

I've seen others complain about this issue in the past, but the only solution I saw was to force the mouseover event on every object to return everything != current object to their normal state. I'd rather not do a general "reset everything" because I have quite a few objects, so I'm wondering if anyone has an alternative they can suggest. I was thinking about storing the last object with the last triggered mouseover in a variable and only resetting that on every mouseover, which could work....

Comment: Did you ever find out what to do here?  I can't seem to work around the onmouseout issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I was required to perform a "reset" on all the other objects to return them to their normal state when another object triggered a mouseover. My project was a labeled map of the US with certain cities showing on mouseover. Each of these cities were children to a state, and had to inherit the mouseover properties in order to no negate the previous mouseover event. It was just a mess. Works fantastic in other browsers, though... Good luck. If you figure anything out, please update this post.

Comment: Mine was also a map of the US.  For IE, I ended up adding a global tracking variable, "current", which is used to reset the previous state that was hovered over.  When the next state is hovered over, the onmouseover method resets the previous state first, then updates the variable with the current state.  This also let me reset a state that was previously hovered over by selecting a state from a download list thatrovides the same functionality but without the map.

Comment: A good solution exists at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908812/combining-raphael-and-jquery-to-achieve-browser-compatibility

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Raphael 2.0.2, there's been an issue in Raphael and Internet Explorer (all versions) where various manipulations of a path such as resetting a transform, `.toFront()`, or `.toBack()` called from `hover()` while hovering can cause hover ins to loop endlessly and/or hover outs to be missed.

While `hover` mostly works fine in IE for mouseout, there are a few things I've found that that can trip it up, causing it to a) ignore mouseouts as you describe and b) trigger the mouseover event recursively such that if you put a console.log in there, IE developer tools' console breaks and turns grey... which sometimes seems to also stop it recognising mouseouts.

Here are the things I've encountered which cause this:

- Resetting a transform, which would cause the element to move from under the mouse, then reapplying it putting the element back under the cursor. non-IE carries on like nothing happened and works fine, IE freaks out as described above.
- .toFront() and .toBack() - non-IE recognises the moved element as being the same element in the same X Y position, IE freaks out as described above.

There are some observations and demonstrations in **this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vw4d6/318/)** (read & uncomment the various comments).

A good workaround here, is to have some kind of flag like for example 'path.data( 'hoverIn', true );`on mouse in and 'path.data( 'hoverIn', false );` on mouse out, then wrap any `.toFront()` or offending transforms in a check that `!path.data( 'hoverIn' )` so that it can only happen once until the mouse out happens. Or, store a reference to the most recently hovered path somewhere after the `toFront()` or whatever, then don't `toFront()` or whatever if this path is also the most recently hovered one.

Comment: Quick credit - jsfiddle adapted from an answer to this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908812/combining-raphael-and-jquery-to-achieve-browser-compatibility

Comment: +1. .toFront() was tripping up mouseout on IE8 for me. Removing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (map with regions that changed background on hover) and the deal-braker  in IE9/Opera for me was the toFront() method. I removed that and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I gone around this limitation by putting code inside anonymous function and then calling it via `setTimeout` inside event handler.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a rect as a background underneath (and containing) the object you are trying to mouseout of, you can effectively get a mouseout effect by adding another hover event handler to the background rect.