# Raphael ID Different on iPad than on browser

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

so I am making a browser based game using raphael v2 to serve up some nice vector maps which zoom. I am using a lot of "getById(xx)" calls which works fine cross browser. But when testing on my iPad the call does not work. I used a firebug applet on the iPad so I could see what the internal id's for each shape was. On desktop I am getting 52 and on the iPad I am getting 69.

Has anyone else run into this issue?
Any resolutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to save the ID of an element when you create it into a separate data structure? Then you can just use this data structure when you need to reference an element, and that way your program won't be as tightly coupled to the internals of Raphael JS, and shouldn't be as liable to breaking with future updates of the library.

Comment: Yes, you can use element.id(); to set the id of the element. Was hoping there was a less hardcode way of doing this. Oh well I suppose.

Comment: Admittedly, I've only done a little Raphael dev, so there might be a better way out there. What are you trying to get the elements for? If it's for events, such as clicks and the like, I found [this SO question pretty handy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908812/combining-raphael-and-jquery-to-achieve-browser-compatibility)